# Is it possible to setup unmanaged DLL to generate memory dump files?

Tags: c#, c, dll, memory-dump

I have a Console C# application that's calling into an unmanaged C DLL to perform calculations. The C DLL generates Access Violation exceptions at times and I want to capture the memory dumps.  I use the code below to setup the C DLL to generate the memory dump files.  My problem is that the SolverExceptionHandler function never gets called.  Do I need to setup the memory dump files' generation in the C# .EXE or am I doing something wrong in the C code below?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <minidumpapiset.h>
#include <errhandlingapi.h>
#include <ExtStruct.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fileapi.h>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>


static const WCHAR MemoryDumpFileDirectory[] = L"\\MemoryDumpFiles";

LONG WINAPI SolverExceptionHandler(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ExceptionInfo)
{
    printf("Entered SolverExceptionHandler\n");

    WCHAR memoryDumpFileName[MAX_PATH_LEN + 1];
    wcscpy_s(memoryDumpFileName, MAX_PATH_LEN, MemoryDumpFileDirectory);
    wcscat_s(memoryDumpFileName, MAX_PATH_LEN, L"\\");
    wcscat_s(memoryDumpFileName, MAX_PATH_LEN, L"DumpFileXXXXXX");

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
        (LPCWSTR) memoryDumpFileName,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION mei;
    mei.ThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    mei.ClientPointers = TRUE;
    mei.ExceptionPointers = ExceptionInfo;
    bool success = MiniDumpWriteDump(
        GetCurrentProcess(),
        GetCurrentProcessId(),
        hFile,
        MiniDumpNormal,
        &mei,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    wprintf(L"SolverExceptionHandler saved Memory Dump into the [%] file. Success: %s", memoryDumpFileName, success ? "True" : "False");

    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hDllInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (dwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            printf("Attaching the SolverExceptionHandler\n");
            SetLastError(0);
            SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(SolverExceptionHandler);
            printf("Did attach the SolverExceptionHandler. GetLastError: %d\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: The callback registered with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() is only called when there's an unhandled exception.  Problem is, it isn't unhandled.  The pinvoke marshaller provides a catch-em-all backstop to raise an SEHException (typically) into the calling C# code.  So yes, invoke the dump in your C# code, ideally by *not* catching the exception and letting the program terminate through an AppDomain.UnhandledException event.  AddVectoredExceptionHandler() is notable, its callback will be invoked, but you do have to be selective since it will see every exception.

Comment: Thanks very much @HansPassant for your answer!  I did setup my Console application with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;` on the first line of main().  I'm noticing 2 things:

1.  There's no trace of UnhandledExceptionHandler being invoked.

2.  I'm seeing an "Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory..." message in the Console, but the call stack ends at the last C# method that calls into interop.  That's not what I need, I need to see the unmanaged context where the exception occurred.